# Check if a specific window is open

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows

I have a window in vim opened (current file) and another one in split called `[Scratch]`.
I want to check if the `[Scratch]` is open or not.

Any example is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `[Scratch]` itself is that that's not really the name of a buffer, but just Vim telling you that this scratch buffer is actually unnamed...

It's much easier if you start with a named buffer and use `bufadd()` to create it. For example:

```
let bufnr = bufadd('MyFancyScratchBuffer')
execute 'sb' bufnr
setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
" Use `setlocal buflisted` if you want it
" to show up in `:ls` too.
```

Then at this point you can search for it by name, with:

```
let winid = bufwinid('MyFancyScratchBuffer')
```

And here you can look at `winid`. If it's -1, then that means the buffer is not loaded into a window (in the current tab!) So you can create a new split for it:

```
sb MyFancyScratchBuffer
```

Otherwise, you can just go to the window already open with that buffer:

```
call win_gotoid(winid)
```

An alternative to using `bufadd()` and naming your buffer is to save the buffer number for it as it's first created. For example:

```
if !get(g:, 'my_scratch_bufnr')
    " Create new scratch buffer and store
    " its buffer number in a global variable.
    new
    setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
    let g:my_scratch_bufnr = bufnr()
else
    " Find if it's loaded in a window in current tab.
    let winid = bufwinid(g:my_scratch_bufnr)
    if winid < 0
        " It's not, so open it into a split.
        execute 'sb' g:my_scratch_bufnr
    else
        " Already open, so go to that window.
        call win_gotoid(winid)
    endif
endif
```

If you're writing your code in a plug-in file, then you can use `s:` variables for script-local variables rather than `g:` for global ones, that way you don't need to worry about name clashes with other plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few plugins that have started to use `{name}://{whatever}` to name scratch buffers (e.g. `tags://patternsearched`, `tasks://...`, ). This is kind of helpful when other plugins try to do things on buffers but wish to ignore *scratch* buffer. A typical example is a local-vimrc plugin that applies project configuration settings on every buffer under a certain directory.

Now we can also filter on `&buftype==nofile` to find scratch buffers as they usually tagged as such. It will help find scratch buffers, but not necessary point to the single scratch buffer you are looking for.

```
" will display the list of buffer numbers with a "nofile" buftype
:echo filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") == "nofile"')
```

By applying `bufwinnr()` on the results, you'll see if they are displayed (>=0) in a window or not (-1).